# Using iterrows() to fill text into column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use iterrows() to fill predetermined substrings (Name and Age) in the column 'Unique Code' with the values coming from the other two columns - 'Name'and 'Age'. However while the loop prints the correct output - 'Unique Code' values do not update?

```
lst = [['tom', 25, 'EVT-PS-Name-Age' ], ['krish', 30, 'EVT-PS-Name-Age'],
       ['nick', 26, 'EVT-PS-Name-Age'], ['juli', 22, 'EVT-PS-Name-Age']]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['Name', 'Age', 'Unique Code'])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row['Unique Code'] = str(row['Unique Code'])
    row['Age'] = str(row['Age'])
    row['Unique Code'] = row['Unique Code'].replace('Name', row['Name'])
    row['Unique Code'] = row['Unique Code'].replace('Age', row['Age'])
    print(row['Unique Code'])
    
df.head()
```

This is my intended outcome - thanks!

```
lst = [['tom', 25, 'EVT-PS-tom-25' ], ['krish', 30, 'EVT-PS-krish-30'],
       ['nick', 26, 'EVT-PS-nick-26'], ['juli', 22, 'EVT-PS-juli-22']]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['Name', 'Age', 'Unique Code'])
```

Comment: `df['Unique Code']='EVT-PS-'+df['Name']+'-'+df['Age'].astype(str)`?

Comment: yes-  can do this - but I wanted to understand why this code would not work?

Comment: @FilippoSebastio [From the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) *You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use loop/iterrows in your code you can assign
using this snippet at the end of your for loop:`df["Unique Code"][index] = row["Unique Code"]`

As per why this does not work, The row variable defined by the loop here is a temporary one and does not affect the dataframe rows.